# Pytest mocked function takes too long to run

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm learning to use mocking while writing unit tests. But my tests always take the time it would take if I was not mocking them. Consider this example function:

**application.py**

```
from time import sleep
    
def is_windows():
    # fake slow operation
    sleep(5)
    return True


def get_operating_system():
    return 'Windows' if is_windows() else 'Linux'
```

**application_test.py**

```
from application import get_operating_system


# 'mocker' fixture provided by pytest-mock
def test_get_operating_system(mocker):
    # Mock the slow function to return True
    mocker.patch('application.is_windows', return_value=True)
    assert get_operating_system() == 'Windows'
```

For some reason this test always takes more than 5 seconds to run. If I remove `sleep(5)` from `is_windows()` then the test runs in under a second, so it looks like the function isn't being mocked at all! Am I doing something wrong here? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm running my tests from PyCharm.

Comment: I added my timing outputs, but something else is going on in your setup. What are your directories looking like, how is the test being run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `application` if you want to mock something in it.

```py
import application

def test_get_operating_system(mocker):
    # Mock the slow function to return True
    mocker.patch('application.is_windows', return_value=True)
    assert application.get_operating_system() == 'Windows'
```

Otherwise, you aren't using the patch.

---

edit: Actually, maybe I'm crazy about that. You code mocks it as expected. I have run it on my machine and it works correctly.

##### outputs

no patch:

```
1 passed in 5.03s
```

with `mocker.patch("application.is_windows", return_value=True)`:

```
1 passed in 0.02s
```

with `mocker.patch("application.is_windows", return_value=False)`:

```
1 failed in 0.10s
```

Comment: I tried this on my machine and it still takes over 5 seconds!!

Comment: Thanks @theherk. You were right about having to import the module and calling the mocked function as application.get_operating_system(). Although this specific example works even if not called this way, my actual test code doesn't (the function's output is not mocked) and the test fails.